# fill a form field in Django views

Tags: python, django

I am trying fill in a value to one of my form fields.

The form has the following fields:

1. Username
2. referral
3. Email
4. Password
5. confirm-password

I want to automatically fill the `referral` field from the `views.py` but can't get it right. any Ideas?

Views.py

```
 def consultant_register(request):

     field_name = 'referral'
     obj = ReferralResponse.objects.last()
     referral_code = getattr(obj, field_name)

     form = ConsultantSignUpForm(request.POST, initial={'field':referral_code})


     if form.is_valid():
        my_model = form.save(commit=False)
        my_model.referral_code = referral_code
        my_model.save()
        login(request,user)
        return redirect('/')
    return render(request, 'accounts/consultant_register.html',  {'form': form})
```

Comment: Please, share the  `ConsultantSignUpForm`  code with us.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided information, you need to provide the correct form field name:

```
form = ConsultantSignUpForm(request.POST, initial={'referral': obj.refferal})
```